# Linux shell: change Perl code to linux shell, grep line by line

Tags: perl, shell, grep

The follwoing code is Perl script, grep lines with 'Stage' from hostlog. and then line by line match the content with regex, if find add the count by 1:

```
$command = 'grep \'Stage \' '. $hostlog;
@stage_info = qx($command);
foreach (@stage_info) {
    if ( /Stage\s(\d+)\s(.*)/ ) {
        $stage_number = $stage_number+1;
    }
}
```

so how to do this in linux shell? Based on my test, the we can not loop line by line, since there is space inside.

Comment: En. Ok. In Perl we can get the matched part $1 and $2. So beside the number how to get these values in linux shell? Thanks!

Comment: you have to use sed to reformat the file if you need details of match parts.  alternatively perhaps you can use shell expressions to dissassemble the line into the parts you need.

Comment: Asking for code translations is explicitly off-topic on SO. Post your shell code, and people will certainly be willing to help you fix specific problems with it, but they won't write it for you.

Answer (score 2):

That is a horrible piece of Perl code you've got there. Here's why:

1. It looks like you are not using `use strict; use warnings;`. That is a huge mistake, and will not prevent errors, it will just hide them.
2. Using `qx()` to grep lines from a file is a completely redundant thing to do, as this is what Perl does best itself. "Shelling out" a process like that most often slows your program down.
3. Use some whitespace to make your code readable. This is hard to read, and looks more complicated than it is.
4. You capture strings by using parentheses in your regex, but you never use these strings.
5. Re: `$stage_number=$stage_number+1`, see point 3. And also, this can be written `$stage_number++`. Using the `++` operator will make your code clearer, will prevent the uninitialized warnings, and save you some typing.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "<", $hostlog or die "Cannot open $hostlog for reading: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/Stage\s\d+/) {
        $stage_number++;
    }
}
```

Comment: while those comnents are valid critique this does not answer the question posed. also, wrong regex.

Comment: No, it is not "wrong". As I explained, there is no point in capturing anything, wherefore parentheses are not needed, and hence there is no need to add the `\s.*` part which matches whitespace and anything. Also, yes, it does answer the question, in the greater aspect of being Perl code that can actually be used, and therefore translated. The greater answer here being that there is no benefit to using a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything with the internal captures, so why bother? You could do everything with a `grep`:

```
$ stage_number=$(grep -E 'Stage\s\d+\s' | wc -l)
```

This is using extended regular expressions. I believe the GNU version takes these without a `-E` parameter, and in Solaris, even the `egrep` command might not quite allow for this regular expression.

If there's something more you have to do, you've got to explain it in your question.

Comment: fortunately he's using linux, and so, GNU grep.  `grep -E` is the same as `egrep`  `grep -c` will return a count directly without needing `wc -l`

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the `-c` parameter. That's standard in all versions of `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

this is almost it.  bash has no expression for multiple digits.

```
#!/bin/bash 

command=( grep 'Stage ' "$hostlog" )

while read line 
do
  [ "$line" != "${line/Stage [0-9]/}" ] && (( ++stage_number ))
done < <( "${command[@]}" )
```

On the other hand taking the function of the perl script into account rather than the operations it performs the whole thing could be rewritten as

```
(( stage_number += ` grep -c 'Stage \d\+\s' "$hostlog" ` ))
```

or this

```
stage_number=` grep -c 'Stage \d\+\s' "$hostlog" `
```

if, in the original perl, stage_number is uninitialised, or is initalised to 0.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what i need. but it seems have some syntax error around <( $command ) part. I am new to linux shell can you make sure? Thanks.

Comment: ok, I have actually tested these versions now they should work for you. don't forget to set hostlog to or replce $hostlog with the apropriate filename.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly, you should be able to do this just fine in the shell:

```
while read; do
    if echo ${REPLY} | grep -q -P "'Stage' "; then
        # Do what you need to do
    fi
done < test.log
```

Note that if your grep command supports the -P option you may be able to use the Perl regular expression as-is for the second test.